# Blcokchain corrupt ledger

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

What happen to the node if we find that node on blockchain has corrupt ledger?

Is the ledger sync with other ledger or get discard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node will never be in sync with its peers. Synchronization process will stop as soon as it find the corruptd data

Comment: Then what happen to corrupt node, is it terminate from block chain or something..

Comment: Since its not accepted by peers its rejected from blockchain. You can imagine it a way like that of Uncle blocks